# How do I check the website design clones?

Tags: website-design, copyright

Let's say a I have a corporate web-site. I can imagine that it would be pretty easy to download my HTML, CSS and JS files, change texts and images to thieve's needs and voilà - there is a new clone!

I could try to look cloned images or texts but it is definitely not a reliable way as thieve can use his own images and texts within my design.

So is there any tools (both free or paid) to keep track web-site **design** clones?

Please keep in mind that I don't need a tool for texts and images clones: I know how to use Google Images search or a tools like Advego Plagiatus.

Comment: You can use something like http://nerdydata.com to search for code, src, or comment similarities. Its not the best case answer, and their bot doesn't crawl *everything* but its a method.

Comment: @dhaupin Thank you for the contribution! I tried this link, but I didn't get the main idea how I should use it: if I put the relatively small part of code in the search window - I'm getting thousands of 'clones', if I put whole HTML doc I didn't have enough patience to have any result. So I think I need to have some methodology to choose the right part of code to use this tool in a proper way...

Comment: yes you should find a very specific part of code you know they are copying, or put a bit of code in your site buried deep as a trigger. This can be a certain comment in code, or even just a unique class on some div. You can do the same thing in stylesheet, just make a fake rule that doesn't do anything. If they copy, search for those things. Hope that works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this question belongs to this forum, but since this topic has been bothering me for a long time I'll try to provide some answer anyways.

In short: Why bother? Your question is probably as old as creative work, the creative process itself. As long as there is original art work, people will copy it – if they like it. This has happened before with fine art, music, design, fashion, … People have always been quoting and copying other people's original ideas – and after my opinion that is an important part of the creative process. That's exactly how the creative field works. And now of course the same also happens to webdesign.

The big difference to other creative fields you also pointed out is, that nowadays people can just dl your css, literally copy it – and they instantly have *your original design formular*. But a) no serious designer will probably do just that – there is way too many free wordpress themes and templates etc. out there. I would consider the effort of stealing and then modifying other people's css files way too time consuming.

And on the other hand; how/ why did *you* come up with the ideas you came up with? Maybe you yourself saw some other design you liked and did your own interpretation of that?

Round-up: try not to bother too much about other people copying your design. You also probably wouldn't want somebody to claim that your design grew on her/his ideas. Instead you may try to feel flattered and spend your time making new, original art work instead of hunting down '*thieves*'.

Comment: In the age of spam, its a worthwhile concern. I would vote that this topic belongs in pro webmasters. Look at Amazon -- there are hundreds of Chinaspam cloning their site layout/media to phish orders for fake NFL, Vuitton, Nike, etc. One offender that comes to mind is Deepak Mehta FIE fake host. I know for a fact at all times he runs at least 5 Amazon clone sites selling Vuitton under different domains. If it happens to them, it can happen to any large company.